# How can I modify the control/option/command key mappings in the IntelliJ's Emacs keymap?

Tags: macos, intellij-idea, emacs, keymaps

GNU Emacs on Mac OS X, by default, uses the **control** key as *CTRL*, and the **command** key as *META*. This drives me crazy, because my MacBook Pro contains only a single **control** key on the left, while I'm used to having a **control** key on both sides of the keyboard.

With my GNU Emacs installation, I was able to modify the variables `mac-control-modifier`, `mac-command-modifier`, and `mac-option-modifier` so that **command** acts as *CTRL* and **option** acts as *META*.

How can I accomplish the same thing in IntelliJ IDEA? It's easy to select "Emacs" as the keymap, but I don't see any way make a similar remapping of *CTRL* and *META*. I know I could remap these keys globally in the OS, but I don't want to do that. I also know I could go in to each and every action and individually modify them, but that seems like a poor solution.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's may be not the easiest solution but you can open the resources.jar (/Applications/IntelliJIdea.app/lib/resources.jar on MacOS) file, locate the Keymap_Emacs.xml (in idea directory) copy and modify it.

And then you can create a new keymap in IntelliJ for updating it with the new content (~/Library/Preferences/IntelliJIdea90/keymaps on MacOS).

That way you can change all your keymap without changing each action individually.

Comment: Thanks Colin, that worked fine (and was quite easy). The only thing I'd add to your answer is that placing a straight copy of the (packaged) `Keymap_Emacs.xml` won't work; Idea 9.0 throws a keymap error when booting up. Instead what I ended up doing is opening the Keymap section in Idea's settings, selecting the Emacs keymap, clicking *Copy*, then making one modification, than applying the change. I then opened up the generated keymap xml in `~/Library/Preferences/IntelliJIdea90/keymaps` and performed my search and replace of **control** with **meta** and saved it. Everything works perfectly.

Comment: The format of user keymap has changed. In IntelliJ 14 instead of being a copy of the original, it's now minimal, with a parent attribute on the root element. The only <action/>s that will appear inside are ones that have been overridden by the user. So now after creating your custom keymap in IntelliJ you have copy the action elements out of the packaged Keymap_Emacs.xml into the custom keymap. After that it works nicely.